# Cannot find the requested object in Moon_Apns

Tags: .net, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, x509certificate, moonapns

I am doing apple push notification using Moon-Apns library but i am stuck with an error "Cannot find the requested object".

[image]

[image]

What i am missing here? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you placed the .p12 file in respective location of server.. i think that may be the cause of this error and let me know the problem exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the valid certificate.